# Filing a Jframe from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jdbc

Really jammed up on my project here and I'm fairly new to java and really new to databases. What I've done in my code is fill the "data" object with a bunch of words but what I want to do is fill those frames with info from a database I've made. I've been Googling and search for days and have not found anything that helps me understand what I need to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Project3 extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable table_1;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
String[] columnNames = { "Restaurant", "Dish", "Type", "Price", "Rating" };
Object[][] data = {
        { "Nemo", "Vesuvio", "Pizza", new String("65kr"), new Integer(7) },
        { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) },
        { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false) },
        { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20),
                new Boolean(true) },
        { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false) } };

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Project3 frame = new Project3();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Project3() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(139, 162, 469, 420);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    table_1 = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table_1);
    table_1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table_1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
            { "Nemo", "blah", "Pizza", "65kr", new Integer(7) },
            { "Nemo", "blah", "Rowing", "1 000 000kr", Boolean.TRUE },
            { "Sue", "blah", "Knitting", new Integer(2), Boolean.FALSE },
            { "Jane", "blah", "Speed reading", new Integer(20),
                    Boolean.TRUE },
            { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), Boolean.FALSE },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null },
            { null, null, null, null, null }, }, new String[] {
            "Restaurant", "Dish", "Type", "Price", "Rating" }));
    JButton btnChangeadd = new JButton("Change/Add");
    btnChangeadd.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // CALL CHANGE METHOD HERE
        }
    });
    btnChangeadd.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    btnChangeadd.setBounds(143, 104, 175, 42);
    panel.add(btnChangeadd);
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Welcome RestaurantID");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(264, 56, 260, 36);
    panel.add(lblNewLabel);
    JButton button = new JButton("+");
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // CALL SOMETHING HERE IF YOU WANT
        }
    });
    button.setBounds(66, 248, 40, 29);
    panel.add(button);
    JButton button_1 = new JButton("-");
    button_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });
    button_1.setBounds(66, 289, 40, 29);
    panel.add(button_1);
    JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
    btnDelete.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            //DELETE METHOD
        }
    });
    btnDelete.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    btnDelete.setBounds(344, 104, 191, 42);
    panel.add(btnDelete);
    JButton btnLogOut = new JButton("Log out");
    btnLogOut.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });
    btnLogOut.setBounds(667, 6, 117, 29);
    panel.add(btnLogOut);
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question and where are you stuck?

Comment: see the problem is I've filled in the data myself and being a complete newbie to databases I can't for the life of my figure out what I need to put in this field to make it pull from the database instead of having to manually file it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/), and then study the article [*Table From Database*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/). Also,

- Use constants or factories when available, rather than needless constructors, for example:

  ```
  {"Nemo", "Vesuvio", "Pizza", "65kr", 7},
  {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", 3, true},
  {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", Integer.valueOf(3), Boolean.FALSE},
  ```
- Use the `@Override` annotation to avoid careless overloading:

  ```
  @Override
  public void run() {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Begin to embrace object orientation using the [*Java Collections Framework*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html), in preference to arrays. Note how the examples cited specify formal parameters such as `List<T>`, where `List` is an interface type and `T` is a generic type parameter.

Comment: I'd also add objectify you data (make a Object representation of the data from the database) rather then relying on arrays.  It makes life SO much easier, especially when it comes to dealing with tables, as each object becomes a row - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Good suggestion; thanks. See if I've captured the essence of your suggestion; edit _ad lib_.